# Adobe Air with Iphone

Tags: iphone, air

Are there any tutorials or some info on developing apps for Iphone with Adobe Air? Where to start and what I need for writing apps? Can't find any info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Adobe Flash Professional CS5.5 or later ...

> Adobe Flash Professional CS5.5 lets you publish your ActionScript 3 projects to run as native apps on iOS. You will have access to nearly all the AIR 2.6 and Flash Player 10.2 APIs.

See [this article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html) for more.

Answer (score 2):

The official Adobe documentation : [Building Adobe Air iPhone Apps](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/air_deviphoneapps.pdf) 
Videos and tutorials : [Packaging applications for AIR for iOS](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSb03e830bd6f770ee-29e1e072124c0d552aa-8000.html)